# codeigniter global_xss_filtering with session variables

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, xss

When i set this to default true in the config file I can no longer access my session variables. How do I fix this so I can still have this on and use my session variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSS filtering is affecting the cookie where CI stores the session data.  I would recommend turning XSS filtering off by default and only using it where you need to.